# How to make a view transparent without transparent subview on that

Tags: ios7, uiview

I have a probem like this. We know we can make transparent an `UIView` by changing Alpha value of that view. But I dont want to make transparent buttons which are inside that view. My problem is when I set the parent view alpha, button also get transparent and button title not visible clearly. How can I overcome this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the background color of the `UIView` with variable alpha, like this:

```
view.backgroundColor = [[UIColor white] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5f];
```

Comment: I changed alpha in Interface builder. Not from the code. But then it gives this problem. If I gave this within the code will it affect in different way?

Comment: Changing alpha in the interface builder changes the alpha of the whole `UIView`. This line of code just changes the alpha of the background of the view, not the other subviews.